# Fitting distribution to data

Tags: r, poisson, gamma

The data is a vector containing genetic distances between adjacent markers on a genetic linkage map.  The aim is to identify the distribution that fits the data and identify outliers, if any.  Outliers here would be an adjacent marker pair which is separated by a distance larger than what would be expected given the data.

Fitdist function from 'fitdistrplus' library was used.  An example using gamma and poisson distributions is given below.  I am puzzled that the two distributions do not produce the same plots.  I am interested in the quantile plot and the p-p plot that is generated in the gamma example, but not in the poisson example.

Example:

```
x <- rnorm(50, 20, 2)
library(fitdistrplus)

ygamma <- fitdist(x, 'gamma', method='mme')
plot(ygamma)

ypois <- fitdist(x, 'pois', method='mme')
plot(ypois)
```

Notice the difference between the two plots.

Comment: No code, no data. Suggest improving your question since at the moment it lacks clarity and focus. (It's just too ... what's the right word.... cryptic?)

Comment: Fitting distributions is terribly difficult. It depends a lot on what you want to do *next*. Do you care about the PDF, CDF, or …?

Comment: @ Andy: What I am trying to do is akin to finding an error rate for linkage mapping.  If certain pairs of adjacent markers are too far apart than would be expected, then those will be classified as outliers and treated as such in the publication.  The poisson disribution fitdist plots aren't telling me much.  I want the qq and pp plots.